# Python is truncating my file contents

Tags: python

I have set a task in Python to code a long text file 1-26 for the letters of the alphabet and 26+ for non-alphanumerics see code below:

```
#open the file,read the contents and print out normally
my_file = open("timemachine.txt")
my_text = my_file.read()
print (my_text)

print ""
print ""

#open the file and read each line, taking out the eol chars
with open("timemachine.txt","r") as myfile:
    clean_text = "".join(line.rstrip() for line in myfile)

#close the file to prevent memory hogging
my_file.close()

#print out the result all in lower case 
clean_text_lower = clean_text.lower()
print clean_text_lower

print ""
print ""

#establish a lowercase alphabet as a list   
my_alphabet_list = []
my_alphabet = """ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.,;:-_?!'"()[]  %/1234567890"""+"\n"+"\xef"+"\xbb"+"\xbf"

#find the index for each lowercase letter or non-alphanumeric
for letter in my_alphabet:
    my_alphabet_list.append(letter)
print my_alphabet_list,
print my_alphabet_list.index

print ""
print ""

#go through the text and find the corresponding letter of the alphabet
for letter in clean_text_lower:
    posn = my_alphabet_list.index(letter)
print posn,
```

When I print this I should get (1) the original text, (2) the text reduced to lower case and no whitespace, (3) the code index used and finally (4) the converted codes.  However I can only get the latter part of the original text or if I comment out (4) it will print all the text.  Why?

Comment: The text file I used is at Project Gutenberg HG Wells "The Time Machine" but any long file should suffice.  I think the final print command should be indented.  Sorry but by "comment out" what I meant was formatting a section of the code as a comment to disable it.  Hope this is clearer.

Answer (score 2):

The bit at the end:

```
for letter in clean_text_lower:
    posn = my_alphabet_list.index(letter)
print posn,
```

keeps reassigning `posn` without actually doing anything with it. Therefore, you will only get the `my_alphabet_list.index(letter)` for the last letter in clean_text_lower.

To fix there's a couple things you could do. First thing that springs to mind is initialize a list and append values to it i.e:

```
posns = []
for letter in clean_text_lower:
    posns.append(my_alphabet_list.index(letter))

print posns,
```

Comment: All that seems to do is produce a comma separated list of the same code numbers.

Comment: Thanks but all that seems to do is comma separate the numbers as a list.  My question is still why the original textfile (which I took from Project Gutenberg and is a long narrative of the HG Wells novel) does not output completely, until one of the other output sections (e.g. the code numbers) is disabled by commenting it out.  I wondered what could be limiting it?

Comment: @grumpster3, I would have no idea why it's not "outputting correctly" until you "comment out a section" as, well, I have no idea what you actually mean by that. From your question, I interpreted it as wanting the code for the entire text file, not the last letter, which is what I answered. Is there a different thing you wanted?

Comment: The text file is at Project Gutenberg "HG Wells The Time Machine".

Comment: I see that the final line needs to be indented to work correctly.

Comment: By "comment out" what I meant was disabling a section of the code relating to 1 of the 4 outputs which it produces, by formatting it as a comment with Geany.  Sorry, hope that makes more sense now.